# Appending for in loop iterations to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a for in loop which iterates through some JSON and outputs three distinct values for each iteration. From what I've read, it is best not to do the appending inside the for loop, rather, it is best to save the values to arrays and append outside the loop.

My question is, if I have three arrays containing my values, say book title, author and URL -- how would I append these so they appear as below? Rather than in three separate lists of all the values.

```
Book Title
Author
URL

Book Title 
Author 
URL
```

Comment: why don't  you create a list and add item one by one from your json.

Comment: can you show us what you get by now? Can you show the for loop?

Comment: That's what I want to do but I don't know how. I can make three separate lists, i.e. a list of book titles, a list of authors and a list of URLs, but I can't seem to make them appear as above.

Answer (score 3):

You can always create a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment):

```
var data = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
// Create empty fragment
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
// My iteration that will append items to the fragment
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
   var item = document.createElement('span');
   item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]));
   fragment.appendChild(item);
}
// After my iteration i will append my fragment 
//   to the place in the page I want my newly created items to appear. 
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all three arrays have the same length:

```
var titles = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3'],
    authors = ['Author 1', 'Author 2', 'Author 3'],
    urls = ['URL 1', 'URL 2', 'URL 3'],
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0, len = titles.length; i < len; i++) {

    var title = document.createTextNode(titles[i]),
        author = document.createTextNode(authors[i]),
        titleEl = document.createElement('h1'),
        authorEl = document.createElement('h2');

    titleEl.appendChild(title);
    authorEl.appendChild(author);

    fragment.appendChild(titleEl);
    fragment.appendChild(authorEl);

    if (urls[i]) {
        var url = document.createTextNode(urls[i]),
            urlEl = document.createElement('p');
        urlEl.appendChild(url);
        fragment.appendChild(urlEl);
    }

}

document.body.appendChild(fragment)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a try. Though occasionally a book has no URL so I guess that would break it as the arrays would be different lengths.

Comment: Yes, but then you have a general problem with your arrays. If the position is just missing in the URL-array, you don't know to which of the next books the URL belongs. You should fill up these missing URLs with `null` in the URL-array. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I'll adjust my code so it adds null to the array if the JSON value is empty.

Comment: Okay, I changed the code. Now it will only display the URL, if it's available (not null).